# Same code, different results? What's wrong with including from other project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, include, syntax-error

**Hello everyone.**

I have a problem with Visual Studio (2017 Community) or the compiler.
I have used a file named **OutputStream.h** in my main project and it works fine, no compile errors.

However, if I want to use it in my other project by doing:

**#include "..\Engine2\OutputStream.h"**

I get following error:

**C4596 '<<': illegal qualified name in member declaration --> y:\dx-engine\engine2\outputstream.h**

It seems misleading that it compiles in main project, so I assume the error is not caused by syntax. Anyway, here's the code:

```
#pragma once

#include <sstream>
#include <Windows.h>

struct SpecialCode { int code; };
extern SpecialCode msgbox ;
extern SpecialCode console;

class OutputStream {
protected:
    std::stringstream stream = std::stringstream("", std::ios_base::app | std::ios_base::out);
public:
    OutputStream();

    OutputStream & OutputStream::operator<<(int data);
    OutputStream & OutputStream::operator<<(double data);
    OutputStream & OutputStream::operator<<(SpecialCode finish);
    OutputStream & OutputStream::operator<<(char * data);
    OutputStream & OutputStream::operator<<(const char * data);
};
```

The error appears in first line with **<<**, but if I remove it, it appears on the next line...

If I remove all lines with **<<** then it compiles.

**Thanks for any help.**

Anyway, can it have something to do with the project settings? Like when you set "strict" in Visual Basic?

Comment: Why did you qualify all those `operator<<` with `OutputStream::` inside the class definition?

Comment: OK.  That's the header.  Now show us a minimal source file that includes it and works, and a minimal source file that includes it and doesn't.  (Ideally `#include "..\Engine2\OutputStream.h"` will the entire contents of both files.)  Then show us the compiler command line used to compile the files (my guess is a difference in the options selected.)

Comment: @Caninonos Oh, that's the mistake :) Thanks ... I just needed it to be done somehow... and compiler ate it...

Answer (score 3):

My mistake was that:

```
OutputStream & OutputStream::operator<<(int data);
```

should be

```
OutputStream & operator<<(int data);
```

I just thought this is not a cause, because it worked previously.

I've learned a lesson. Don't write code, that just works and you are not entirely sure, how it works :)

**Someone with same issue may want to look into this:**

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators